# Mode Inheritance how to implement ModelForms (Inerithance?)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i'm recently moving my db to a model Inheritance structure. Here an example:

Task model

```
STATUS_CHOISE = (('PR', 'In process'), ('ST', 'Stopped'), ('FN', 'Finished'), ('DL', 'Deleted'),)
class Task(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    date_created = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False) 
    date_deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)), auto_now_add=False)
    parameters = jsonfield.JSONField()
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOISE, default='ST')
```

here the HumanTask that extends Task

```
PLATFORMS = (('CC', 'CrowdComputer'), ('MT', 'Amazon Mechancial Turk'),)
class HumanTask(Task):
    number_of_instances = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, default='')
    page_url = models.URLField(max_length=400, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=PLATFORMS, default='CroCo')
    validation=models.OneToOneField(ValidationTask)
    reward = models.OneToOneField(Reward, null=True, blank=True)
```

now, how should i create the Form? Should i use ModelForm for both classes?
The point is: there are fields that have to be `exclude`

for example, TaskForm is:

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    process = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Process.objects.all(),widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ('date_deadline', 'date_created','parameters','status','objects')
```

so what i want for the `HumanTaskForm` is that the exclude are inherited from the `TaskForm` 
i tried with this

```
class HumanTaskForm(TaskForm):
    class Meta:
        model= HumanTask
        exclude = 'uuid'
```

but does not work.

Summing up: is this correct? should i use Inheritance for forms? and, how can i have excluded fields, and others parameters, Inheritance?

Comment: `exclude` needs to be a tuple.

Comment: true but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leverage the `exclude` from `TaskForm` in `HumanTaskForm` and extend it, you can inherit the Meta class from TaskForm:

```
class HumanTaskForm(TaskForm):
    class Meta(TaskForm.Meta):
        model = HumanTask
        exclude = TaskForm.Meta.exclude + ('uuid',)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit the parent Meta as well as.

The child class will inherit/copy the parent Meta class.  Any attribute explicitly set in the child meta will override the inherited version.  To my knowledge there is no way to extend the parent Meta attributes (ie adding to 'exclude').

```
class AwesomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AwesomeModel
        exclude = ('title', )

class BrilliantForm(AwesomeForm)
    class Meta(AwesomeForm):
        model = BrilliantModel
```

.

```
print(AwesomeForm.Meta.model)
> AwesomeModel

print(BrilliantForm.Meta.model)
> BrilliantModel

print(AwesomeForm.Meta.exclude)
> ('title', )

print(BrilliantForm.Meta.exclude)
> ('title', )
```

You could do something like this:

```
class BrilliantForm(AwesomeForm)
    class Meta(AwesomeForm):
        model = BrilliantModel
        exclude = AwesomeForm.Meta.exclude + ('uuid', )
```

.

```
print(BrilliantForm.Meta.exclude)
> ('title', 'uuid')
```

Comment: what if i've fields in the AwesomeForm? 
right now i don't see them in the BrillaintForm.
Plus, how can i call and check the validation on AwesomeForm when BrilliantForm is submitted?

Comment: If you're inheriting from a Form class that already has a `clean` or `clean_[field]` method defined, those methods would be called from the child class, unless you override them.